# After boot, need to restart smbd to get printer sharing to work. Is it starting before cups?

Tags: samba, printing

As the title says, after I reboot I need to restart smbd to get printers to show up over smb.  My thought was that maybe smbd is set to start before cups and gets messed up?  This is with 11.04, how I do I check the startup order of startup dependencies?
Thanks,

Comment: If that is the case I would consider it a bug... Please try my answer and if it is not a solution to your problem you need to have another look at your problem ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `/etc/init/cups.conf` you can add a line where you tell upstart it needs to wait for samba to be loaded. This is the relevant part:

```
start on (filesystem
      and (started dbus or runlevel [2345])
      and stopped udevtrigger)
stop on runlevel [016]
```

Adding a

```
and started smbd
```

will have `cups` wait for the samba daemon.

Comment: Thanks this helped.  But the file is actually in /etc/init/*, and I added a wait for cups in the smbd.conf

Comment: fixed it. thanks for accepting it. Please consider adding in your solution and accepting that one.